# WPF TabControl with 'new tab' button?

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I have a `TabControl` in a WPF app, and I want to add a 'new tab' command to the tab strip (like tabbed web browsers have).

I've had a look at the template in Blend for the `TabControl`, but I can't figure out how best to add my new button to the right of the last tab. What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: I've implemented such control recently, it has the same functionality as the control in the answer has, but at the same time I've left the default design of this control and implemented it for Silverlight as well as for WPF. I just leave it here: http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/silverlight-tabcontrol-with-scrolling-and-with-the-new-tab-button/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's about 30 ways to do this, but this CodeProject link might be what you are looking for:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfTabControl.aspx

It has a "New" (although it's on the left, rather than on the right like Google Chrome).  It's a drop-in control, rather than a bunch of complicated Xaml styling.  I'm personally still looking for the crazy Xaml style for this, but in the interim this control is working pretty darn well.  Possibly it does exactly what you need.

Hope this helps,
Anderson